# org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource15 could not be instantiated

Tags: python, elasticsearch, databricks

Working on `Databricks` workspace with the `Python` language inside the `cluster`. I want to connect to Elasticsearch Remote server and bring data to Databricks workspace to work on.

- When I check the connection with `Elasticsearch` remote server, connection is succeeded:

  ```
  #ELasticsearch server connection
  %sh 
  nc -vz hostname port
  -----------------------
  Connection to hostname port [tcp/*] succeeded!
  ```
- However when I try to read data from Elasticsearch using the `spark.read` method with the Elasticsearch connector, an error occurs:

  ```
  Error message:
  java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
  org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister:
  Provider org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource15 could not be instantiated
  ```
- Source code that's written in Databricks workspace is as following:

```py
df = (spark.read
      .format( "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql" )
      .option( "es.nodes",   hostname )
      .option( "es.port",    port     )
      .option( "es.net.ssl", "false"      )
      .option( "es.nodes.wan.only", "true" )
      .load( f"index_name" )
     )

display(df)
```

Error full stack trace:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider 
org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource15 could not be instantiated

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2516541018203898>:4
      1 # NOTE: We **must** set the es.nodes.wan.only property to 'true' so that the connector will connect to the node(s) specified by the `es.nodes` parameter.
      2 #       Without this setting, the ES connector will try to discover ES nodes on the network using a broadcast ping, which won't work.
      3 #       We want to connect to the node(s) specified in `es.nodes`.
----> 4 df = (spark.read
      5       .format( "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql" )
      6       .option( "es.nodes",   "ip-address" )
      7       .option( "es.port",    port     )
      8       .option( "es.net.ssl", "false"      )
      9       .option( "es.nodes.wan.only", "true" )
     10       .load( f"index-name" )
     11      )
     13 display(df)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:48, in _wrap_function.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46 start = time.perf_counter()
     47 try:
---> 48     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49     logger.log_success(
     50         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
     51     )
     52     return res

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:302, in DataFrameReader.load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    300 self.options(**options)
    301 if isinstance(path, str):
--> 302     return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    303 elif path is not None:
    304     if type(path) != list:

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions.py:228, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    226 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    227     try:
--> 228         return f(*a, **kw)
    229     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    230         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o566.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource15 could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.access$700(ServiceLoader.java:323)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator$2.run(ServiceLoader.java:407)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:409)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:46)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:303)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl$(TraversableLike.scala:297)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterImpl(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter(TraversableLike.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter$(TraversableLike.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:240)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.$less$colon$less
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ClassLoaders$LibraryClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 39 more
```

- Research on the issue that I've done so for:

  1. The Error is related to `DataSourceRegister` interface in `Apache Spark` which is used for registering data sources
  2. As far as I understand there is compatibility issue with the dependency. Particularly I presume that, `Elasticsearch Connector` and `Spark Version` in `Databricks` workspace are not compatible.
  3. But couldn't find any reliable sources on the issue, and still couldn't configure the correct versions to work.

Comment: Could you please share the full error stack trace? I would be expecting some more information underneath the error line you shared with us.

Comment: @Koedlt Hi there, unfortunately that's all what I got from the Databricks workspace~

Comment: Hmm, I'm expecting this to be an issue in conflicting versions of your dependencies. To solve this, though, I would need to know what the full error stack trace is. Is it possible your errors are written to some log files somewhere?

Comment: Nope, there is no any log files, in Databricks workspace you type your source and get the output just below the source code. And you are right about the dependency. It's installed in the cluster library page. So as far as I know based on the Databricks->Elasticsearch Documentation , there is a required dependency `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:8.4.3` from `Maven`. But even after including the previously mentioned, it's giving the error, from my analysis I understand the dependency version is conflicting with Elasticsearch version. So I think that's sort of Databricks issue

Comment: Because simply when I use Rest API based on Maven, I can easily connect and bring the data from Elasticsearch remote server~ The purpose of my question is that, I've been wondering whether anyone has experienced the same issue on the same working environment~

Comment: Please post full stacktrace

Comment: I found the full stacktrace and updated the post, thanks